# How to retrieve tags in xml using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Below is my xml doc:

```
<arm_group>
  <arm_group_label>Phase I, Part A </arm_group_label>
  <arm_group_type>Experimental</arm_group_type>
  <description>Dose escalation </description>
</arm_group>
<arm_group>
  <arm_group_label>Phase I, Part B </arm_group_label>
  <arm_group_type>Experimental</arm_group_type>
  <description>Dose escalation and safety </description>
</arm_group>
<arm_group>
  <arm_group_label>Phase IIa - Part A Expansion </arm_group_label>
  <arm_group_type>Experimental</arm_group_type>
  <description>Repeated administrations </description>
 </arm_group>
```

Below is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ids = []
contents = []
for file in os.listdir('xml/'):
    if '.xml' in file:       
        tree = ET.parse(f'xml/{file}')
        root = tree.getroot()
        armGrpLabel =[]
        for x in root.findall('arm_group/arm_group_label'):
            armGrpLabel.append(x.text)
        armGrpType = []
        for x in root.findall('arm_group/arm_group_type'):
            armGrpType.append(x.text)
        armDesc = []
        for x in root.findall('arm_group/description'):
            armDesc.append(x.text)
       armGrpLabel = '\n'.join(armGrpLabel).replace('\t','').replace('\n\n','\n').replace('\r','')
        armGrpType = '\n'.join(armGrpType).replace('\t','').replace('\n\n','\n').replace('\r','')
        armDesc = '\n'.join(armDesc).replace('\t','').replace('\n\n','\n').replace('\r','')
 text =  (armGrpLabel) + '\n\n'+(armGrpType) + '\n\n' +(armDesc)
        contents.append(text)
        ids.append(file[:-4])
```

**am getting output like below:**

Phase I, Part A

Phase I, Part A

Phase I, Part A

Experimental

Experimental

Experimental

Dose escalation

Dose escalation and safety

Repeated administrations

**But,want output like below:**

The output should be like the below:

Phase I, Part A

Experimental

Dose escalation

Phase I, Part B

Experimental

Dose escalation and safety

Phase IIa - Part A Expansion

Experimental

Repeated administrations

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it could be done with xmlstarlet.
You would just need to do something similar in python.

```bash
xmlstarlet sel --template --match '/*/*/*' --value-of 'text()' --nl input.xml
```